# Visual Basic 2010- Retrieving images using code

Tags: vb.net, image, file, resources

I am making a card game. I have 53 images for the cards and one for the back of the cards. Is there a way I can use the resource file or is there a way I can reference the folder where the program is being held with it still being relatively portable so I can move the folder and the program will still work perfectly. I thought about using a case statement and using the

```
My.Resources._8Hearts 'For Example
```

but that would take up a lot of space that I am sure can be avoided. I know this can be used to grab an image:

```
card1.image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\" & variable_so_I_can_get_multiple_cards & ".png")
```

And using a 'for' statement to place each card in a different slot on the form

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(picPath)` can retrieve an image for you,no need to add to resources in VB,and im sure u have worked with Strings so you can dynamically attach the name of each picture name (and I think also extension,.PNG seems to work best for me).

If you need it to move with the installation folder find out what your application path is using `MessageBox.Show(Application.StartupPath)` and then place a folder of your pictures in there and when publishing don't forget to include the folder yah? And **Inno Setup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php)** is a good publishing tool...so I hear,never used it before.

If this answer works for you please dont forget to accept it as the right answer